# Could not load XML with version 2.0 in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I load an xml document from a file stream as below

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();                    
xmlDoc.Load(a_Stream); // a_Stream is an System.IO.Stream
```

This works fine when the XML version is 1.0 but if i load XML with version 2.0 , it throws some exception (System.Exception._COMPlusExceptionCode & Version number '2.0' is invalid. Line 1, position 16.).

It is required to load xmls with version 1.0 and 2.0 also.

Not sure what should i do for this?

Comment: Well there is nothing as **some exception** may be you missed the name

Comment: see edit update for exception..,

Comment: I think your trying to use format version for your own versioning as hinted in my answer. Please comment on the answer if it does not explain/match your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `<?xml version="1.0"?>` (and trying to use 2.0 instead of 1.0) then:

- .Net supports only 1.0 version of the XML.
- The latest version is 1.1 ( see http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/xml#w3c_all).

So specifying `<?xml version="2.0"?>` should cause some exception.